# Github action - echo within an expression

Tags: github-actions

```
  changes:
    name: Detect changes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      aws: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.aws }}
      azure: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.azure }}
      gcp: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.gcp }}
    steps:
    - name: Checkout source code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Check for changes
      uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: filter
      with:
        filters: |
          aws:
            - added|modified: 'aws/**'
          azure:
            - added|modified: 'azure/**'
          gcp:
            - added|modified: 'gcp/**'


  zip_files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: changes
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: montudor/action-zip@v1
        with:
          args: zip -qq -r result.zip "$(${{needs.changes.outputs.aws}} && echo aws)" "$(${{needs.changes.outputs.azure}} && echo azure)" "$(${{needs.changes.outputs.gcp}} && echo gcp)"
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: my-artifact
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/result.zip
```

I want to zip directories that detect changes. and then upload it to artifact.

When zipping, I get a "zip error: Nothing to do" even though aws/azure/gcp all evaluate to true. I think that the error lies within the args line.

Comment: Please show logs. Also, perhaps add a simple echo statement to demonstrate that the outputs are set in the second job.

Comment: What is the output you expect from the `$(${{needs.changes.outputs.aws}} && echo aws)` expression? From what I understand it will return something like `$(true && echo aws)`, when you would actually just want to return the `aws` folder for it to be added to the zip file, correct? (same thing for azure and gcp)

Comment: I made a test [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester41.yml) and I think that would be closer to what you're expecting for the workflow behavior. ([workflow_run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/2542045895) as reference). Let me know if it's correct :)